# Can you specify which metadata to export in Lightroom other than the few standard selections?

Tags: lightroom, metadata

Can you specify which metadata to export in Lightroom other than the few standard selections? In the export dialogue you can select to export everything, just copyright, just copyright and contact info, everything but camera and Camera Raw info and also toggle the geolocation on and off. What I'd like to do is to be able to select exactly what fields to include or at least get more control over the metadata export than these thin options. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the plugin [Jeffrey's Metadata Wrangler](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/metadata-wrangler). There you can specify excatly which Metadata you want to export with your images.

Comment: It seems like a great plug-in. It's not possible to do out of the box then?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I always use this plugin if I need that kind of control about metadata exports.