# Exporting All Metadata When Exporting JPGs & NEFs To Reduced Size JPGs

Tags: lightroom, metadata, jpeg

In Lightroom, when Exporting NEF and JPG files to reduced size JPGs, How do I get all metadata to export as well? Specifically, my exported files don't include Date Taken or Tags.

Comment: [Answering your own question is explicitly encouraged on Stack Exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), so please just post your answer here so it can be useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When you export, go to the "Metadata" section and check that you have chosen the option "All Metadata" :

[image: LR export Metadata Options]]

This is a screenshot from LightRoom CC.

You might also be interested by the following questions :

- [Can you specify which metadata to export in Lightroom other than the few standard selections?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48332/can-you-specify-which-metadata-to-export-in-lightroom-other-than-the-few-standar)
- [How can I force Lightroom to export metadata for all photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18045/how-can-i-force-lightroom-to-export-metadata-for-all-photos)